# scala parallel array with map and flatten

Tags: arrays, scala, parallel-processing, implicit-conversion

Below, in my `calculateLegalMoves` method, I'm wanting to execute the `map` call in parallel for each of the array elements.  I've found that in order to appease the compiler, I had to convert to a parallel array and convert back to a normal array after the calculations are performed.  Is this correct?  Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
class Knight extends Piece {

  val candidateMoveCoordinates : Array[Int] = Array(-17, -15, -10, -6, 6, 10, 15, 17)

  override def calculateLegalMoves(board: Board) : Array[Move] = {
    val possibleMoves : ParArray[Option[Move]] = candidateMoveCoordinates.par.map(candidate => checkLegalMove(candidate, board))
    possibleMoves.toArray.flatten
  }

  private def checkLegalMove(x: Int, board: Board) : Option[Move] = {
     //not implemented yet
     None
  }

}
```

Comment: There isn't any way around the two conversions, but you could combine the `map` and `flatten` together and use `flatMap`.

Comment: OK thanks.  Can you provide that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way around the two conversions. The parallel collections provide a `seq` method to get back to a sequential collection, but here it gives an `ArraySeq`, which is not what we want. `collection.breakOut` can be used to do a `map` and a conversion to a different collection type in one shot, but when used here it forces the `map` to be done sequentially.

However you could combine the `map` and `flatten` together and use `flatMap`:

```
override def calculateLegalMoves(board: Board) : Array[Move] = 
  candidateMoveCoordinates.par.flatMap { candidate =>
    checkLegalMove(candidate, board)
  }.toArray
```